# Matlab - parameters to gaussian filter creation

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to create multiple gaussian filters in a loop like so:

```
for sigma:3:0.4:15
    filter = fspecial('gaussian', 6*sigma, sigma);
end
```

It doesn't like me passing a float to the size parameter, and gives me the following error:

```
Expected input number 2, N, to be integer-valued.
```

But when I change the line of code to this:

```
filter = fspecial('gaussian', uint8(6*sigma), sigma);
```

I get this error:

```
Expected input number 2, N, to be one of these types:
double
Instead its type was uint8.
```

I'm fully baffled, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The function is expecting an integer (i.e. a whole number) of type double. That argument determines the size of the matrix that is returned, so it doesn't make sense to pass a fractional argument there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/images/ref/fspecial.html) implies that if the first argument of `fspecial` is `'gaussian'`, the second argument is to be an integer. This does not imply anything on the expected type of the argument, only that it has to be a rounded number.

From your second try and the resulting error, I understand that the expected type of the second argument is a `double`.

Therefore the command you are looking should be something like

```
filter = fspecial('gaussian', floor(6*sigma), sigma);
```

or something close (see the [floor function documentation](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/floor.html) for alternative functions to round real numbers to integers).